# how to transform between pages with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

there is my html code for switch user to some pages in my php website

```
    <div class="nav">
    <ul onChange="showUser(this.value)">
        <li class="active">
            <div class="fix">
                <span class="ico"><img src="image/ico7.png"></span>
                <span class="value">manager</span>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="chengePass.php">chenge pass </a></li>
                <li><a href="search.php">search</a></li>
                <li><a href="distroy.php">exit</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>

         <li class="active">
            <div class="fix">
                <span class="ico"><img src="image/ico3.png"></span>
                <span class="value">show user</span>
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

it work good but i want to learn how can I transform between pages with ajax code, by click on a list item codes calling from page b and show in page a. so it will be faster than html code
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.load` function of jquery to load a `page` in a `div` like this

```
function LoadPage(url){
 $('#yourMainDiv').load(url, function (response, status, xhr) {
 //you can put you logic here
 });
}
```

Here `url` will be `url of page` which you want to load in the div.

You will call it like

```
LoadPage('chengePass.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do like say in first answer but add `href="#" onclick="LoadPage('chengePass.php');return false;"`

```
 <a href="#" onclick="LoadPage('chengePass.php');return false;">link</a>
```

or

```
 <li onclick="LoadPage('chengePass.php');return false;">link</li>
```